# GIMP get layer position relative to the image

Tags: python, gimp

i'm coding in python-fu and i need to get the layer position relative to the image (eg. the layer starts at x=35, y=50)

Is this possible? I haven't found anything in the gimp pdb docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, got it.

It's layer.offsets (property) for future reference.

:)